# IFormFile IEnumerable is of size 1 even though multiple file upload is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Model

```
    public List<ZertifikatFiles> Files { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Certificates { get; set; }
```

View

```
<form asp-action="AddCertificate" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-file-dragndrop>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">
        <input type="file" asp-for="IFormFiles" multiple />
        <span asp-validation-for="IFormFiles" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>  </form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddCertificate(Certificates certificates )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (certificates.IFormFiles != null && !certificates.IFormFiles.IsEmpty())
            {
                certificates.Files = new List<CertificateFiles>();
                foreach (IFormFile formFile in certificates.IFormFiles)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[formFile.Length];
                    using (var reader = formFile.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        await reader.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)formFile.Length);
                    }......
```

Whenever I try to upload more than one file, the IEnumerable only takes the first file and leaves the rest behind.

[image: Choose Files, 3 Files chosen]

Translated: Choose Files, 3 Files

Even though I specified the multiple file upload in the input field, the `certificates.IFormFiles` delivers me a size of 1.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `multiple="multiple"` instead of `multiple` in file input

Comment: Doesnt make a difference. `certificates.IFormFiles` still has the size of 1.

Comment: can you show the html form code ?

Comment: does your form tag have this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few discussions with the team, I found out that the custom property attribute `data-file-dragndrop` only allows 1 file to be sent via AJAX. You were still able to upload more than one file but the AJAX-Request only accepted one file. In the case where you uploaded more than one file, the AJAX-Request took the first file and left the rest behind.

We all did not know this until the one who created this attribute explained it to us. I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Try to update your question to resloved and explain the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you used .Net core 2.0 or 2.1, try to update your SDK to 2.2.203 then it will work without problem.
the issue not in your code, it was a bug in .NET core 

I invite you to read more about this bug here : https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8527

Comment: I'm currently using .Net core 2.2.102. Should I still update it?